# "Do Not Disturb" on iOS iMessage does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications, do-not-disturb

When I mute a group conversation in **Messages** (by enabling “Do Not Disturb” in the Details screen of the thread), I still get a notification with every new message. This happens regardless of whether everyone in the group is using an iPhone or mixed (non-iOS and iOS). This also happens when my phone is both locked and unlocked.

I am running iOS 10.3.3, but it's been happening for some time. Is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is how **Do Not Disturb** was designed for text conversations. This feature blocks *sound* notifications and *that’s it*.

In fact, it works the same way the global **Do Not Disturb** works, with one major difference: going into Settings → Do Not Disturb and setting *Silence* to `Always` does NOT block banners or alerts for muted threads. The only way to disable those is by disabling them for ALL incoming text messages, or by activating the global **Do Not Disturb**.

If you are displeased with Apple’s implementation of this feature and believe it should work differently, I strongly advise you to [voice your feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/messages.html).

[Many people](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26904476#message26904476) would [agree with you](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOS8/comments/2epefb/the_new_do_not_disturb_feature_for_chatty_group/), as a quick search will reveal.

Comment: Do Not Disturb in iMessage doesn't even block sound for me. it's like it's not even working.